# Send an email to an employee based on selected item from dropdownList?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Please allow me to explain this as best as possible.

We have two tables, RequestTypes (a look up table) and Work_Request

RequestTypes table has three fields, requestTypeID (PK), RequestType, AssignedTo_email(the employee who will be handling the request)

Sample data:

```
RequestTypeID            RequestType              AssignedTo_email
1                         Repairs                 repair@domain.com
2                         Cleanup                 cleanup#doamin.com
3                         Software Development    swd@domain.com
```

Work_Request has several fields but for the purpose of keeping it streamlined, I will show a few relevant fields. They are work_requestID (PK), rquestTypeID (FK to requestTypes table), entery_date, entry_time, RequestersName, requestersEmail, RequestersPhone, IssueDescription

There is a RequestTypes dropdownlist that is dynamically populated from the RequestTypes table shown below:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Type_of_Request" data-placeholder="Please select request type..." class="chosen-select form-control" style="width:250px;height:178px;" tabindex="3" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="100px" Enabled="True">
          <asp:ListItem value="">&nbsp;</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then codefile for the dropdownList

```
Dim requestTypeccmd As New SqlCommand("Select requestTypeID, Type_of_Request from RequestTypes ORDER By Type_of_Request ASC", New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString))
        requestTypeccmd.Connection.Open()

        Dim RequestTypeValues As SqlDataReader
        RequestTypeValues = requestTypeccmd.ExecuteReader()

        Type_of_Request.DataSource = RequestTypeValues
        Type_of_Request.DataValueField = "requestTypeID"
        Type_of_Request.DataTextField = "Type_of_Request"
        Type_of_Request.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

So far, so good but here is where we are having problems.

Whenever a work request is submitted, an email is sent to the AssignedTo_email which is the individual who will be handling the request.

My question is whether the DB design is flawed because I can't figure out how to grab the AssignedTo_email email address from the RequestTypes table given that dropdownList contains only RquestTypesID and RequestType.

In other ords, When a user selects a requestTypeID of say **1** with the associated requestType of **Repairs**, any ideas how to grab the associated email address of AssignedTo_email so s/he can receive an email regarding the request?

I hope I am making some sense.
Thanks for your assistance in advance

Comment: Um... `SELECT AssignedTo_email FROM RequestTypes WHERE RequestTypeID = @id`?  And use the selected `RequestTypeID` from the drop down list as the query parameter.

Comment: @David,

Thank you. That helps